# Confusing on output result of numpy.power function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, overflow

I am trying to learn numpy. At [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_ufunc_simple_arithmetic.asp), I saw following code:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
arr2 = np.array([3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 33])

newarr = np.power(arr1, arr2)

print(newarr)
```

Here is the results:

[image]

I do not understand why the final element of the result is zero?

Comment: Hint: what's `newarr.dtype` and `(60 ** 33) % 2**64`?

Comment: 0 mean overflow, that occurs during the exponentiation calculation.

Comment: it happens due to integer overflow, if you check, by default you would use int64 and if you overflow 64-bit, it would truncate the result.

Comment: @pyjedy That's seem to imply that "0 means overflow", that is, that each time an overflow occurs, value is replaced by 0. If yes, this is not true. What the overflow does is ignoring all bit the  64 less significant bits of the answer. And in this case, because 60 is a multiple of 4, and 4**33 is 2**66, the 64 (and even the 66) less significant bits of 60**33 are 0. For example, `np.array([61])**np.array([33])` is not 0. I suppose you understand that, but your comment may mislead reader to believe you meant "overflows lead to a 0 answer"

Comment: @Masoud was your doubt clear by the answer?

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
arr2 = np.array([3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 33])

np.power(arr1, arr2)

print(np.power(arr1, arr2))
#[      1000    3200000  729000000 -520093696       2500          0]
```

Here 2 elements are getting overflowed.

```
40**8   #-520093696   for  6553600000000
60**33  #0  for 47751966659678405306351616000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: correct answer, +1. I explained overflow a bit more detailed in my answer

Answer (score 2):

As Brian already pointed out correctly, this behaviour is the result of an [Integer Overflow](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/integer-overflow).

> An integer overflow occurs when you attempt to store inside an integer variable a value that is larger than the maximum value the variable can hold. The C standard defines this situation as undefined behavior (meaning that anything might happen).

You are using an int64, meaning the maximum storable value is power(2,64). Because [power(33,60) trunkated by power(2,64) is exactly 0](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=pow%5C%2840%2960%5C%2844%2933%5C%2841%29%20modulo%20pow%5C%2840%292%5C%2844%2964%5C%2841%29), this behaviour emerges.

Comment: for the detailed explanation+1